# Find indices of true-after-false in a Boolean Pandas Series

Tags: python, pandas, series

I have a boolean series (e.g `pd.Series([True, False, False, False, True, False, True, True, False])`).
I would like to count/get indices of `True` instances that comes after a `False` instance. So for the above example, that would be `Index([4,6])`.
Of course I could iterate over the Series, but When I have dozens of Series with ~10k values that isn't the best practice. I'm wondering if there's a better way of doing this.

Comment: Have you tried using the shift function and equating?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`Series.shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.shift.html) with `fill_value=True` and inverted by `~` with original and filter index by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
s = s.index[~s.shift(fill_value=True) & s]
print (s)
Int64Index([4, 6], dtype='int64')
```

Numpy idea:

```
s = s.index[~np.append([True], s.to_numpy()[:-1]) & s]
```